# VBA Excel: Finding a match between two different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have written some code that is trying to match an ID ("ISIN") that is present on worksheet "A and confirm if it's worksheet ""B. If there is a match, I would like to take the corresponding inputs/values on worksheet "B" and place it on worksheet "A". As of the moment, my condition is not letting me move forward and the vlookup isnt functioning too.

Any tips?

```
'For loop to find the corresponding inputs associated with the ISIN
Dim rgRow As Range
For Each rgRow In datarange.Rows
    
    sISIN = rgRow.Cells(1, 2)
    sInstrument = rgRow.Cells(1, 3)
    sType = rgRow.Cells(1, 4)
    sRegion = rgRow.Cells(1, 6)
    sAssetClass = rgRow.Cells(1, 7)
    sRating = rgRow.Cells(1, 8)
    sRatingDynamic = rgRow.Cells(1, 9)
    sProfil = rgRow.Cells(1, 10)

    ISINmatch = Application.Match(sISIN, listrange.Columns(1), 0)
    
    If sType = "Securities" And sISIN <> "" And Not IsError(ISINmatch) Then
        
            sInstrument = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sISIN, listrange, 2, False)
            sRegion = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sISIN, listrange, 3, False)
            sAssetClass = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sISIN, listrange, 4, False)
            sRating = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sISIN, listrange, 5, False)
            sRatingDynamic = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sISIN, listrange, 7, False)
            sProfil = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sISIN, listrange, 6, False)
            

    End If

 Next rgRow
```

Comment: My guess is you want `listrange.Columns(1)` when using `Match`.

Comment: Hey BigBen thanks for the response, but the fix didnt work. I have been trying the whole day to work it out, but no cigars so far.

Comment: How are you `Set`ting `listrange`?

Comment: Set listrange = listData.Range("F3").CurrentRegion
                                Set listrange = listrange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(listrange.Rows.Count - 1)

Comment: What does `Debug.Print listrange.Address` return in the Immediate Window?

Comment: $F$4:$L$1543 (this is  where the values/data is located)

Comment: And the `sISIN` is for sure found in column F?

Comment: What does "vlookup isnt functioning too" mean? Do you receive errors? Isn't it possible that a match to not exist?

Comment: Is the data in column F:F formatted as string?

Comment: BigBen - yes the sISIN is in column F

Comment: FaneDuru - i have been getting an error that states "Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class"

Comment: This may mean that not a match has been found. Try declaring a Variant variable. `Dim mtch` and then try `mtch = Application.VLookup(sISIN, listrange, 2, False)`. Followed by `Debug.Print mtch`. What does it return. `Application.Vlookup` does not return a fatal error like `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup`...

Comment: an example of an sISIN is BE00046596

Comment: You should do  the `Application.Match` separately and assign the result to a variant variable. You can then check if the value of the variable is an error or not, if it isn't you can use  the value as the row number to get the data you want instead of using `Application.Vlookup`.

Comment: @norie `Application.Vlookup` behaves the same as `Application.Match`. It does not raise a fatal error as `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup` does...

Comment: I know, what I was suggesting was more to do with eliminating the multiple calls to  `Application.Vlookup`.

Comment: I created variable  ISINmatch = Application.Match(sISIN, listrange.Columns(1), 0) and it seems to work. I am seeing the correct input pop up when i hover over the code. But its not printing onto the worksheet now

Comment: There's nothing in the posted code that puts values on a worksheet, all it is doing is setting the values of the variables `sISIN`, `sInstrument` etc.

Comment: norie - im not sure what i would do to get the values of the variables. should i create a nother for loop?

Comment: anyone can help?

Comment: If you update the question with the current code I'll try and post something that will return the data to the worksheet.

Comment: norie that would be remarkable!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what some of the ranges in your code e.g. `DataRange` and `listrange`, refer to but this code should put the relevant values on the worksheet when `sISIN` is found.

Note, you don't really need the variables,you could assign the results from all the `Application.Vlookup` calls directly to the cells.

Also, I suggested in a comment not using `Application.Vlookup` as `Application.Match` will return the row `sISIN` and you could use that to get the values you want.

I would still recommend using that but unfortunately can't really post any code to show how it would work because of the aforementioned problems with the ranges used in the code.

Anyway, here's the code.

```vb
    'For loop to find the corresponding inputs associated with the ISIN
Dim rgRow As Range

    For Each rgRow In DataRange.Rows
    
        sISIN = rgRow.Cells(1, 2)
        sType = rgRow.Cells(1, 4).Value
        
        If sType = "Securities" And sISIN <> "" Then
        
            ISINmatch = Application.Match(sISIN, listrange.Columns(1), 0)
    
            If Not IsError(ISINmatch) Then
        
                sInstrument = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sISIN, listrange, 2, False)
                sRegion = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sISIN, listrange, 3, False)
                sAssetClass = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sISIN, listrange, 4, False)
                sRating = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sISIN, listrange, 5, False)
                sRatingDynamic = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sISIN, listrange, 7, False)
                sProfil = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sISIN, listrange, 6, False)
            
                rgRow.Cells(1, 3).Value = sInstrument
                rgRow.Cells(1, 4).Value = sType
                rgRow.Cells(1, 6).Value = sRegion
                rgRow.Cells(1, 7).Value = sAssetClass
                rgRow.Cells(1, 8).Value = sRating
                rgRow.Cells(1, 9).Value = sRatingDynamic
                rgRow.Cells(1, 10).Value = sProfil

            End If

        End If

    Next rgRow
```